# How to filter out issues on public API?

Tags: sonarqube

Issues which require to modify a public API to be fixed can't be fixed without breaking backward binary compatibility for the users of this API (and the Clirr plugin checks). I would thus like to filter out these issues. Is there an automatic filter for this (I could not find any in https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus)? Or do I have to manually mark them as "Won't Fix"?

For context, this is for the ASM project, and issues such as:

https://sonarqube.ow2.org/project/issues?id=ASM%3Aasm&issues=AV-w56AZ2DWuNN5xTaVz&open=AV-w56AZ2DWuNN5xTaVz

https://sonarqube.ow2.org/project/issues?id=ASM%3Aasm&issues=AV-w56Qo2DWuNN5xTabT&open=AV-w56Qo2DWuNN5xTabT

https://sonarqube.ow2.org/project/issues?id=ASM%3Aasm&issues=AV-w56Li2DWuNN5xTaYC&open=AV-w56Li2DWuNN5xTaYC

https://sonarqube.ow2.org/project/issues?id=ASM%3Aasm&issues=AV-w56Qe2DWuNN5xTabP&open=AV-w56Qe2DWuNN5xTabP

https://sonarqube.ow2.org/project/issues?id=ASM%3Aasm-tree&issues=AV-w6BzG2DWuNN5xTai6&open=AV-w6BzG2DWuNN5xTai6

Comment: Why not change the severity of the referred rules for you specific project?

Answer (score 2):

You found the [right documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus), now it's just a question of how to apply it.

Presumably your public API are gathered into a few packages, so you can **Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria**. So you're going to set up exclusions like:

```
key: squid:S1214
path: **/objectweb/asm/**/*/java
```